# Debian package installed in /proc directory

Tags: installation, package, debian

I created a package which contains some php files. My rules files is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/make -f

icon = $(CURDIR)/rss.jpeg
script1 = $(CURDIR)/index.php
script2 = $(CURDIR)/feeds.conf
script3 = $(CURDIR)/rss_php.php
apacheConfig = $(CURDIR)/rssReader
launcher = $(CURDIR)/cw1-6005-pp6g11.desktop

DEST1 = $(CURDIR)/debian/cw1-6005-pp6g11/usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11
DEST2 = $(CURDIR)/debian/cw1-6005-pp6g11/usr/share/applications

build: build-stamp
build-stamp:
    dh_testdir

    # Add here commands to compile the package.
    #$(MAKE)

    touch build-stamp

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp

    # Add here commands to clean up after the build process.
    #-$(MAKE) clean
    #-$(MAKE) distclean

    dh_clean

install: build clean $(icon) $(script1) $(script2) $(script3) $(apacheConfig) $(launcher)
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_clean -k
    dh_installdirs

    # Add here commands to install the package into debian/<packagename>.
    #$(MAKE) prefix=`pwd`/debian/`dh_listpackages`/usr install

    mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST1)
    mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST2)

    install -m 666 $(icon) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(script1) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(script2) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(script3) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(apacheConfig) $(DEST1) 
    install -m 777 $(launcher) $(DEST2)

# Build architecture-independent files here.
binary-indep: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
#   dh_installmenu
#   dh_installdebconf
#   dh_installlogrotate
#   dh_installemacsen
#   dh_installpam
#   dh_installmime
#   dh_installinit
#   dh_installcron
#   dh_installman
#   dh_installinfo
#   dh_undocumented
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
#   dh_perl
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

# Build architecture-dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
# We have nothing to do by default.

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install
```

I am expecting that the package will be installed under the usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11 directory, though it is installed under /proc/29124/cwd directory

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong.

Note: i run ubuntu 11 via vmware.

Kind Regards,
Pavlos

Answer (score 1):

The `/proc` filesystem is special. There is nothing "installed" there. `/proc/29124/cwd` is merely a pointer to the current directory for process 29124.

You might be able to do:

```
ls -l /proc/29124/
```

to see what `cwd` links to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did what you said, and i realized that it points to /home/ppoliani/INFO6005. This folder contains my package and the directory with the source code. I am wondering, why there is no folder created in usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11?

Comment: Well, this: `DEST1 = $(CURDIR)/debian/cw1-6005-pp6g11/usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11` is not `/usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11`. It's something under `$(CURDIR)`, and I don't know what that is (you might).

Comment: Actually it is the current directory which in my case is  /home/ppoliani/INFO6005. I have read that this is the correct way to define the directories where the source files will be copied. Isn't it?

Comment: No, you've got too much stuff in there. Maybe `DEST1 = /usr/share/cw1-6005-pp6g11` might work, but it's basically up to your make file.